# How can I access the indices of a hit test?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to add a different object to a scene with a hit test, and I am currently only able to add one object. I want to access the second, third and fourth indices in my hit test results in order to to add these objects with a touch.

I have tried accessing through `.indices` but it is not compatible with `UITouch`.

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: sceneView)

        let results = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, types: .featurePoint)

        if let hitResult = results.first {
            let cubeScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/cube.scn")!

            if let cubeNode = cubeScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "cube", recursively: true) {


                sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should I go about this? I have thought about creating one SCNScene, pass it as an array, and then would load all the models from the scene.

Comment: maybe you can do a for loop for the results array instead of just checking if the first element contains something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Samual suggested...  example

```
var hitTestOptions = [SCNHitTestOption: Any]()

    @objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
        {
             let location: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: gameScene)
             let hitResults: [SCNHitTestResult] = gameScene.hitTest(location, options: hitTestOptions)
             for vHit in hitResults
             {
              if(vHit.node.name?.prefix(5) == "Panel")
              {
               gameControl.selectPanel(vPanel: vHit.node.name!)
               return
              }
             }
            }
```